# Can I change the facebook connect button?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

Can I change the default button of Facebook connect by an other picture ?

I am setting up the registration process of my website and would like to use the Open Graph API. The button is pretty ugly and not very user friendly do you know if I can change it by my own ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

With the new connect-js it is quite trivial. Just attach a js click event and then call FB.login(callback)

http://github.com/facebook/connect-js/blob/master/examples/jquery/login.html